# Integrate Blazor into .NET Core ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I built an ASP.NET MVC Core app using .NET Core 3.0. This app was migrated from ASP.NET Core 2.2. It's fairly complex at this point. However, there is one view that I would like to make "richer". So, I was hoping to use Blazor (Server App).

I started by adding a Blazor Server App to my existing solution. My solution setup looks something like this:

```
MySolution
- MyBlazorApp
- MyMvcApp
```

I add added a reference from `MyMvcApp` to `MyBlazorApp`. However, I'm not sure how to actually show the Blazor app, in a view, in my existing `MyMvcApp`. I basically want `MyBlazorApp` nested within a view in my existing `MyMvcApp`. Kind of like a widget. Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Thank you!

Comment: you don't need to do that , you can [Integrating Blazor in an existing ASP.NET Core application](https://fizzylogic.nl/2019/08/18/integrating-blazor-in-an-existing-asp-net-core-application/)

Comment: @NanYu While I don't *need* to that, I do want to have that kind of separation. Is there a way to keep the projects separated?

Comment: As far as the existing MVC app is concerned, the Blazor app is just something that presents a particular page on a particular URL (and that page happens to be a Blazor SPA). This implies that you could do this the same way you'd show *any* third-party content within your pages. If you want deeper integration than that, then the Blazor stuff probably needs to actually be part of your app.

Comment: If you want to separate Blazor from your MVC app, then you would create a Blazor Library. But what you need to do is to integrate Blazor components into your project. Besides the link mentioned by @NanYu, there is the official doc at Microsoft about integrating Blazor components. I did follow it with success: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#integrate-components-into-razor-pages-and-mvc-apps

Comment: Has this question been answered for you @SomeUser ?
I suspect you really need a web assembly component embedded in your MVC razor page. If si, it's very easily done.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use server-side Blazor for **.Net Core 3.0** use step below :

**Integrating server-side Blazor in your web application:**

1. Modify the ConfigureServices method in the Startup.cs file, and add the following code:

   `services.AddServerSideBlazor();`

   This enables the server-side blazor dependencies.
2. Extend the HTTP pipeline with Blazor:

   ```
   // enables endpoint routing in ASP.NET Core
   app.UseRouting(); 

   //maps the endpoints in the application
   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
   {
    // .. Other endpoint mappings
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
   });
   ```
3. Create and host the actual Blazor components

   there you go, it doesn't take a lot to integrate Blazor into existing ASP.NET Core applications

Answer (score -4):

You have to install extension from visual studio which is mentioned below

asp.net core blazor language service

Comment: There is much more to do than just integrate a NuGet package. The project needs to support blazor by adding it to the request pipeline for instance

Comment: @DanielSchmid He is trying to integrate Blazor with .Net core Asp.net MVC(not version of .net core is specified). If he is using .net core 3.0 then simply go here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aspnet.blazor , download and install.